# setting the selectedIndex to the first option below and option group

Tags: javascript

Using only javaScript (no jQuery) how do I set the selected index to the first option below an option group.  When populated the number of options below each group is variable, however in the options array they are numbered sequentially, so it is hard to figure out where one group ends and the next starts.  I have a variable with a reference to the group option id I want to use.

```
<select id="selectBox">
  <optgroup id="optGrp1" label="Group 1">
  <optgroup id="optGrp2" label="Group 2">
    <option value="1585">option 1 in group 2</option>
    <option value="1589">option 2 in group 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup id="optGrp3" label="Group 3">
  <optgroup id="optGrp4" label="Group 4">
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"...the first option below an option group..."* When you say "below," do you really mean **in**? Only one group in your question even has any options in it.

Comment: I don't see a specific reference to my question there?  If you could point to one that would be great.

Comment: To make my example brief, I did not show options below the other groups.

Comment: T.J. gave you links to help you improve your question. You haven't shown us any effort at what you've done to solve your own problem. Please add the JavaScript you tried to your question.

Comment: I can set a specific option using this method document.getElementById('selectBox').selectedIndex = 5.  But that is not useful.  I also tried to get a reference to the id of the option group in the selectBox using an example from w3cSchools like this. var x = document.getElementById("optGrp2");  But that did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kristoffer's first answer was exactly what I needed.  Here is the complete example of the code with his suggestion:

First a call is made to a method in my form class to populate the list box

```
//sample arrays
g.groups = {grpKey1:"label1", grpKey2:"label2"...}
g.options = {grpKey1:{optVal:"optTxt",optVal:"optTxt",...}, 
             grpKey2:{optVal:"optTxt",optVal:"optTxt",...},...}

//a reference to the select box and two arrays are passed to the method 
g.addGroupOptions(document.getElementById("mySelectBox"), g.groups, g.options); 

//this method in my form class populates the list box 
//with group labels and options under each label
this.addGroupOptions = function (selectBox, grpArray, optArray)
{
    for ( var grpKey in optArray )
    {
        var group = document.createElement('optgroup'),
            opt   = document.createElement('option');

        //retrive group label from groups array
        group.id    = grpKey;
        group.label = grpArray[grpKey];

        /*
        loop optArray[grpKey] get each subKey 
        */
        for ( var subKey in optArray[grpKey] )
        {
            opt.text   = optArray[grpKey][subKey];
            opt.value = subKey;
            group.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
        }
    //append option group and subordinate options to list box
    selectBox.appendChild(group);
    }
}
```

Then Kristoffer's suggestion is applied to set the selected item in to the first option in the desired option group.

```
    document.getElementById(document.getElementById( myVariable ).value).getElementsByTagName('option')[0].selected = true;
```

Comment: Note the word 'office' is really a variable, so it should be replaced with a variable with a value of one of the groups id's ie:    document.getElementById( myVariable ).value.  This is what makes the positioning of the selected item work

Comment: You shouldn't mark your own answer as accepted, but the answer that gave you the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var group = 'optGrp2';
var optgroup = document.getElementById(group);
var options = optgroup.getElementsByTagName('option');
if (options.length) {
    options[0].selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that was just what I needed.

Comment: Your first example was the perfect answer     document.getElementById('optGrp2').getElementsByTagName('option')[0].selected = true;